# Accessing the Activity from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to change the activity title from a fragment (in this case, it's an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`). To this end, I save the activity in an attribute on the fragment when `onAttach()` is called on the fragment. According to the docs, `onAttach()` should be called before `onCreateView()`, which I'm using to request some data used to fill up the view. When I kick off the thread for the network retrieval, I want to indicate that in the title, so I'm trying to call `this.activity.setTitle()` from the `Fragment`. However, that keeps throwing a `NullPointerException`. What am I missing here?

Comment: [getActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())

Comment: yes just use getActivity();.....

Answer (score 15):

You can access the Activity in a Fragment using `getActivity()`. It can be called safely as soon as `onActivityCreated()` was called on the Fragment. Before that, it might not be there or might not have been fully initialized yet.

If your thread starts before that, just note the fact somewhere in your Fragment and only change the title after `onActivityCreated` was called.

Comment: That seems to work. It seems pretty weird, though, that I get an actual instance of my Activity for onAttach(), but I can't call any method on it.

Comment: Scratch that... it looks like onActivityCreated() isn't even called on my Fragment?

Comment: Okay, I forgot the argument for onActivityCreated(). It's called, but when I call getActivity().setTitle(String) in it, it still throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: Are you sure it's really the Activity that's null? Probably the title is? I might be wrong, but I doubt that onActivityCreated is called without an Activity actually being there.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can call `requiredActivity()` too that return `FragmentActivity`object and if fragment doesn't come from an Activity, method throws a `IllegalStateException`