# what is similar code for MainActivity.this in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to use this line of code : "mAdapter = new MembersAdapter(_______, membersList);" 
in my fragment class named `HomeFragment` If it used in Activity then it might be written as `mAdapter = new MembersAdapter(MainActivity.this, membersList);`

But now, I want to be executed in Fragment and `for the Fragment` so what should I do ?`

Comment: use this  mAdapter = new MembersAdapter(getActivity() , membersList);

Comment: no please read again both

Comment: I want to pass fragment thing man

Comment: did you got the answer?

Comment: @AarjeIshu this refers to context as a param to the constructor . `getActivity()` will get the context of the activity which hosts the fragment.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29

Comment: @Rajsundar No I did'nt

Comment: Adapter is for fragment class not the Activity So I can not pass getActivity()

Comment: @AarjeIshu just in case could you post the constructor of `MembersAdapter`?

Comment: Nope I tried I can not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the Activity from a Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155136/accessing-the-activity-from-a-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

You can write base activity as Fragmentactivity and use the base activity by extending it to other activity so that base activity is maintained in the fragment class.

```
  youractivity youractivity_object;

  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        youractivity_object= (youractivity) activity;

    }
```

Comment: would you elaborate ?

Comment: Wait I am elaborating

Comment: I am having some Adapter class and View holder classes for views in Fragment class so If They (Views)were for Activity then we might use MainActivity.this but the views are for Fragment

Comment: what is Activity here

Comment: you can use baseactivity that you have already passed to the fragment.

Comment: I want fragment 's context to pass

Comment: you can make base fragment or you need to pass this object. if you use this object the it will you can't pass another fragment object so you can base fragment and extend it to following fragments MainActivity and HomeFragment please refer the following link you will get idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444375/how-to-create-interface-between-fragment-and-adapter

Answer (score 0):

You might try this code:
1/

```
class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
 public interface Adapter2FragementInteraction {
     void onSomeEvent();
 }
 // Override the constructor;
 public Adapter(Adapter2FragmentInteraction listener){
      //Save this listener;
      this.listener = listener;
 }
```

}

2/ In your Fragment:

```
`RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(
    new Adapter2FragementInteraction(){
        @Override
        public void onSomeEvent(){
              //Do something with your Fragment's Views
        }

    }
);`
```

Comment: RecyclerView is super

Comment: Editted my answer, please check