# Get current activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this class for sending email with android

```
    public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {

    private ProgressDialog statusDialog;
    private Activity sendMailActivity;

    public SendMailTask(Activity activity) {
        sendMailActivity = activity;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        statusDialog = new ProgressDialog(sendMailActivity);
        statusDialog.setMessage("Getting ready...");
        statusDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        statusDialog.setCancelable(false);
        statusDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
        try {
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
            publishProgress("Processing input....");
            GMail androidEmail = new GMail(args[0].toString(),
                    args[1].toString(), (List) args[2], args[3].toString(),
                    args[4].toString());
            publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
            androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
            publishProgress("Invio email in corso, sarai ricontattato da un nostro operatore per la conferma");
            androidEmail.sendEmail();
            publishProgress("Email Sent.");
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            publishProgress(e.getMessage());
            Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
        statusDialog.setMessage(values[0].toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        statusDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Without using fragments i use the following code in the MainActivity  to send a mail

```
new SendMailTask(MainActivity.this).execute(fromEmail,
                   fromPassword, toEmailList, emailSubject, emailBody);
```

But now i need to use Fragment and i get an error at this point:
"MainActivity.this its not an enclosing class"

how can i solve this error?

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change below code

```
new SendMailTask(MainActivity.this).execute(fromEmail,
                   fromPassword, toEmailList, emailSubject, emailBody);
```

To

```
new SendMailTask(getActivity()).execute(fromEmail,
                   fromPassword, toEmailList, emailSubject, emailBody);
```

For more details you can check below link.

[Accessing the Activity from a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155136/accessing-the-activity-from-a-fragment)

Answer (score 18):

From fragment to activity use this :

```
((YourActivityName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();
```

From activity to fragment use this :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//include fragment via layout xml
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
fragment.yourPublicMethod();
```