# Pass data from fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been looking for the answer everywhere but can't find the right one. I have tried onAttach methods etc, nothing works.

My goal is to change int value from the fragment inside activity which the fragment is called from or call a function which is inside the activity from the fragment.

**As example 1:**

*I declare inside a Fragment: private int sample = 1;
Inside fragment I press the button and changes sample value to 2.*

**Example 2 with function:**

*I have a function inside a Fragment: public void sample(){}
Inside fragment I call the function sample()*

**How do I achieve this???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a duplicate of this one: [Get current activity from fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891277/get-current-activity-from-fragment)

You can get a Reference to the Activity by calling: getActivity() inside the fragment.

```
MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
```

Also if you want a reference to the Parent Fragment you just need to call: getParentFragment() inside the fragment:

```
MyParentFragment myParentFragment = (MyParentFragment) getParentFragment();
```

Comment: Well the confusion was MyActivity. I thought thats some sort of a class or something, but its just a name of my class activity... omg

Answer (score 0):

declare sample int variable globally and then assign value 2 to sample variable on button click . it will store value 2 and you can access any where in the same fragment .